# Analytic extension of the Hurwitz ζ function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation

For the purpose of formalisation in a theorem prover, I am looking for a simple definition of the analytic extension of the Hurwitz ζ function $\zeta(s,q)$ valid for all $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$ and ideally a large set of value for $q$ (although $q \in (0;1]$ probably suffices).

There are two approaches that I am aware of:

- Using a contour integral representation like in Tom Apostol's ‘Introduction to Analytic Number theory’
- Using the convergent Newton sum representation given by Hasse in ‘Ein Summierungsverfahren für die Riemannsche ζ-Reihe’

Are there any other methods? Choosing the ‘right’ definition can make a huge difference in formal proofs, so: Which one is likely to be the ‘easiest’ or most elegant, or has the most rigorous and explicit proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing by parts, using the binomial series and inverting the double sum works fine, obtaining

$$\zeta(s,a)-s \zeta(s,N) 
= \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n ((n+a-1)^{-s}-(n+a)^{-s})\\+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty {-s \choose k+2} ((a-1)^{k+2} -a^{k+2}) \zeta(s+k+1,N)$$
Taking $a=1$ shows $(s-1)\zeta(s,N)$ is entire, from which you obtain that $\zeta(s,a)-s \zeta(s,N)$ and hence $(s-1)\zeta(s,a)$ is entire.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please go into more detail here? I don't understand the steps here at all.

Comment: Is there perhaps some connection to the Euler–MacLaurin summation formula?

Comment: @ManuelEberl No. Use summation by parts and the binomial series to obtain $\displaystyle\zeta(s,a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+a)^{-s} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) ((n+a)^{-s}-(n+a+1)^{-s})$ $\displaystyle =\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1-s} ((1+\frac{a-1}{n})^{-s}-(1+\frac{a}{n})^{-s})$ $ \displaystyle= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1-s} \sum_{k=0}^\infty {-s \choose k} ((a-1)^k - a^k) n^{-k}$ then change the order of summation

Comment: All right, thanks. I'll see what I can do with this.